# Error Installing ruby with RVM Single User mode on Arch Linux

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've just installed RVM on ArchLinux x64 in single user mode via the recommended install script

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

I've also installed all the requirements listed in `rvm requirements`

However, I'm having trouble actually installing any version of ruby. And getting the following error:

```
arch:~ % rvm install 1.9.3
No binary rubies available for: ///ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/christopher/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  460k  100  460k    0     0   702k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  767k
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/christopher/.rvm/src
Prepare yaml in /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Configuring yaml in /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/home/christopher/.rvm/usr ', please read /home/christopher/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make', please read /home/christopher/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Installing Ruby from source to: /home/christopher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p194 to /home/christopher/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /home/christopher/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoreconf not run successfully?
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling
Error running 'make', please read /home/christopher/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The log files are as follows:

```
arch:~ % cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log 
__rvm_log_command:32: permission denied: 
arch:~ % cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log     
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
arch:~ % cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log     
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Did you try to run `rvm install` with different users? Just asking because the log has the following entry `__rvm_log_command:32: permission denied` which looks like the installer fails to write to a log file (which might make one of the scripts end unexpectedly)

Comment: Chris, I just did a fresh installation of the latest ArchLinux x64 version and I was able to install rvm + ruby 1.9.3 without any issues :S.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same problem on two machines running Mac OS 10.6.8.

I was able to fix the yaml problem by manually cd-ing into the directory and running ./configure. eg:

```
$ cd /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/christopher/.rvm/usr
```

After running "rvm install 1.9.3" a couple more times, it picked up the configuration I'd done, and stopped bothering me about the yaml issue.

I was also able to cd into the ruby directory and configure and make it. eg:

```
$ /home/christopher/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

...However, this didn't cause rvm to pick it up.  I'm guessing I was missing some necessary command line options and flags.

But considering I was able to get as far as I did, it seems to me like it's an rvm bug.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now: "rvm get head && rvm install 1.9.3".  The stable branch doesn't work.